# addEventListener / onchange not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, outlook-addin

I'm developing a javascript plugin for outlook.

For it to work on outlook desktop, I need it to run on Internet explorer 11.648.
Because in the case of Outlook Desktop the underlying browser is IE.

Following piece of code works in chrome, firefox and microsoft edge but not in IE 11. Function doesn't get called.

```js
document.getElementById("upload_docu").addEventListener("change", function() {
  readURL(this);
}, false);


function readURL(input) {
  console.log("Read url called.");

  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('.image-upload-wrap').hide();

      $('.file-upload-image').attr('src', e.target.result);
      $('.file-upload-content').show();

      $('.image-title').html(input.files[0].name);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    file_name = input.files[0].name;
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('document', input.files[0], input.files[0].name);
    console.log("Read url before url");

    var url = "https://dev.paksign.pk/api/v1/profile/" + localStorage.getItem('profile-uuid') + "/document/"

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem("jwt_token")
      },
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(data) {
        document_id = data.uuid;
        button = document.getElementById("upload_next");
        button.disabled = false;

      }
    });

  } else {
    removeUpload();
  }
}
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />

<div class="file-upload">

  <div class="image-upload-wrap">
    <input class="file-upload-input" type='file' id="upload_docu" accept="" />
    <div class="drag-text">
      <h3>Drag and drop a file.</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Other options**

Tried following solutions, they too failed in IE.

```
$('#upload_docu').on("change", function(){ readURL(this); });

<input class="file-upload-input" type='file' id="upload_docu" onclick="readURL(this);" accept="" />

<input class="file-upload-input" type='file' id="upload_docu" onchange="readURL(this);" accept="" />
```

Comment: Might not be supporting FileReader API. Can check if `window.FileReader` is defined for starters

Comment: There is no conclusive evidence regarding the support of FilereaderAPI because function is not called, there is nothing printed in console.

Comment: Does your IE browser say 'Internet Explorer restricted  this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls' anywhere? Once I clicked "Allow" your code worked as intended and properly called the onchange function

Comment: No, where did you get this warning? Console?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What if remove everything from the function `readFile` except the `console.log`; do you get the output then? If so, how much code can you add until it does not run anymore?

Comment: Function is not getting called. There is a console.log in the first line but there is nothing in the console.